# WebClient Exception, does not support concurrent I/O operations

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, webclient, stack-trace

I have a static class which return new instance of webclient

```
public static class WebAccess
{
    public static WebClient GetWebClient()
    {
        return new WebClient();
    }
}
```

Then I use this class to hit page like this

```
WebAccess.GetWebClient().DownloadString(new Uri("http://" + WLCDomainUrl + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["urlClearCache"].ToString() + "/?id=" + Request.QueryString["id"] + "&Type=RC"));
```

I don't want to catch the response

but it is throwing exception most of the time

```
WebClient does not support concurrent I/O operations.

Stack Trace:

   at System.Net.WebClient.ClearWebClientState()
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
   at UpdateCache.ProcessLocationCacheRequest(String locId, Boolean isChain) in 

WebClient does not support concurrent I/O operations.

Stack Trace:

   at System.Net.WebClient.ClearWebClientState()
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(Uri address, String method, String data)
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(String address, String data)
   at CacheClassLibrary.ServerClass.APIServer.Create(String Id, String MobileWLCUrl) in
```

Any help?? I'm not able to figure it our as I'm serving each request with new instance of web client :/

The application gets multiple request at same time.

Comment: From what you've shown, it should technically be correct.  Can you show a more complete code sample with all the requests?  Are you certain you are not reusing any of the `WebClient` instances anywhere else in the code?

Comment: @mellamokb I have used web client only..... planning to use httpreq in some parts as want some async calls in code

Answer (score -5):

try this

```
public static class WebAccess
{
    WebClient instance;
    public static WebClient GetWebClient()
    {
        if (instance == null)
           instance = new WebClient();

        return instance;
    }
}
```

then you have only one instance of WebClient class

Comment: what difference it would make? i will not give the new instance everytime, I want to remove this exception? will it help? i guess no!

Comment: Switching to one `WebClient` instance would be a step *backwards*, and definitely not solve the problem.

Comment: Why Singleton are Evil/Anti-pattern : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottdensmore/archive/2004/05/25/140827.aspx Very interesting post, you should read it :)